# How can we redirect to required angular page (routing page) from spring boot controller - angular integrated inside spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, redirect, angular-routing

I have integrated angular application inside spring boot application.. i.e. angular build files are placed inside static folder of spring boot application like following image.
[image]

```
I have defined two angular routing urls like

 1. http://localhost:8080/pageone
 2. http://localhost:8080/pagetwo
```

when I access above `urls` from browser, which `are handled by server` (spring boot application) directly and `not by the angular`. so `I end up in page not found`.

`We can redirect to index page` from spring boot like this

```
@GetMapping("/")
public RedirectView welcome(RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    //attributes.addFlashAttribute("flashAttribute", "redirectWithRedirectView");
    //attributes.addAttribute("pageToRequest", "paymentoverview");
    return new RedirectView("index.html");
}
```

`but` we can `only redirect to index.html` page `not to routing urls "/pageone" or "/pagetwo"`.

I don't want to end up in index page.

```
Somehow I wan't to end up in respective page that I accessed from browser automatically, 
even after redirect to index page also fine.
```

I tried to send attributes along with index.html, but it doesn’t work.
How can we fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution..

Access below urls from browser

```
1. http://localhost:8080/pageone
2. http://localhost:8080/pagetwo
```

Request will reach spring controller directly and will be handled by below controller

```
@Controller // should not be @RestController
public class BaseController implements ErrorController { // implement ErrorController to handle 404 (error pages)

    // Always redirect to index.html page (only option)

    // Can handle all request (which end up in 404)
    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }

    // Specific request 
    @GetMapping("/pageone")
    public String pageone() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }

    // Specific request with pathvariable and requestparam
    @GetMapping("/pagetwo" + "/{id}")
    public String pagetwo(@PathVariable("id") String id,
                                  @RequestParam("param1") String param1,
                                  @RequestParam("param2") String param2 ) {
        // both pathvariable and requestparam will be sent to front end
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}
```

Index page will be dispatched after that angular automatically load requested page, for example : '/pageone' or 'pagetwo'

app-routing.modules.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pageone',
    component: PageOneComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'pagetwo/:id', // to handle pathvariables
    component: PageTwoComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
  ]
```

You can access received pathvariable and requestparam as below

PageTwoComponent.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')); // get pathparms
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => { // get queryparams
      console.log(params['param1']);
      console.log(params['param2']);
  });
  }
```

In short, `@Controller` and `implements ErrorController`

```
@GetMapping("/error")
public String error() {
   return "forward:/index.html";
}

After that angular automatically load requested page (routing url)
```