# Angular refresh routing children Server Error

Tags: angular, apache

My project is deployed on subDirectory server Apache,
my base index it's
`<base href="./"> or <base href="/myFolder/">`,

the problem is when i'm on route children page, example:

```
www.mysite.com/search/meetings
```

all ok, but when i'm on it and refresh the page i receive Internal Server Error.
Also when trying to navigate to a child route via its url, the page fails to load and responds with 500 Internal Server Error.

How i can fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: is angular integrated inside java spring boot application (tomcat server) ?

Comment: if that so you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083643/how-can-we-redirect-to-required-angular-page-routing-page-from-spring-boot-con/70096427#70096427

Answer (score 1):

please read the first answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

You need to implement **catch-all stragery** or you can use **hashlocation strategy**

Comment: Hi, i know this method: provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy OR { useHash: true }, but i dont want the # on the URL

Comment: then use the catch-all strategy as mentioned in the linked question first answer, in which you need to redirect all error pages to index.html